# how to install gcc4.8 in netbsd 6.1.3?

Tags: gcc, netbsd

I did a "make install" for lang/gcc48 in pkgsrc.  It did built ok.  However, when I do gcc --versions, the default gcc 4.5.3 is displayed.  What steps do I need to do after the build?

Comment: Not a BSD user but as a quick guess: Check your `$PATH`.  It's evaluated left to right, which decides what will take precedence (the first gcc found).

Comment: The binary probably needs to be called as something other than gcc. maybe gcc48?

Comment: What is the result of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: the $PATH  is /home/alg/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11R7/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/pkg/bin:/usr/pkg/sbin:/usr/games:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I just added the right path and it worked.